# Fuzzy file diff

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can find several resources on fuzzy searching, but nothing on fuzzy file/string comparison. Is there any way to compare files while ignoring simple differences (like dates and email addresses)?

I was thinking about a function/tool that I can pass 2 strings to and a list of regular expressions. The return would be a list of diffs except for ones that match the regular expressions passed.

As a first pass, I was thinking about wrapping `difflib` and testing the pairs of differences against the regular expressions passed, but is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: You could anonymize things like dates and email addresses, assuming you can identify them.  If you go through the file a couple of times with `re.sub` then you can replace all the dates  with `00/00/0000` for example, and do the same for other data. I'd set it up like with a generator pipeline that consumes a string and yields out the anonymized version of that string

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This would be an easier approach as I was running into difficulty wrapping difflib while still getting its full functionality. I could instead pass a dictionary to the function: `{'PLACEHOLDER': regexp}` where, in the case of dates, you could have a list of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a list of tuples, where each tuple has a regular expression and a string

```
[(r'\d\d?/\d\d?/\d\d\d\d', '00/00/0000'), ...]
```

We can build a pipeline of generators out of this that will perform successive substitutions using `re.sub` to obfuscate the differences in things like date, time, email addresses etc.

```
import re

def replace(pat, repl, iterable):
    pat = re.compile(pat)
    for string in iterable:
        yield pat.sub(repl, string)

def reader(filelist):
    for name in filelist:
        with open(name) as f:
            yield f.read()

filelist = ['filename1.txt', 'filename2.txt', ...]
patterns = [(r'\d\d?/\d\d?/\d\d\d\d', '00/00/0000'), ...]
source = reader(filelist)
gen = source
for pat, repl in patterns:
    gen = replace(pat, repl, gen)
for string in gen:
    print(string)
```

In the last `for` loop, `gen` is a generator that yields the sanitized contents of the files.  Here I print them, but you can write them back to files, save them, analyze them one at a time, or run some iterative `diff`.

Comment: Will this approach open the file for each replacement that is done? I am not very familiar with using generators.

Comment: @anon01 No.  The file will be read into a string which we then perform all of the operations on.  This happens in `reader`.  The rest of the pipeline only deals in strings. I recommend [David Beazleys presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) if you want to think more about generators this way