# performing fuzzy differences between 2 files

Tags: python, diff

When doing some retrocomputing stuff, I sometimes have to compare 2 MC68000 disassembled executables of the same game.

Games are published using different languages (english, french...) or have slight modifications / revisions.

The code is roughly the same but the global labels are shifted because of previous code changes (or data which is wrongly interpreted as branches which generate more or less fake labels, depending on the data) so I can have for the first file:

```
LAB_0012:
     MOVE  #0,D0
     MOVE  #2,D2
LAB_0013:
     RTS
```

and for the second file:

```
LAB_0015:
     MOVE  #0,D0
     SUB   #3,D1
     MOVE  #2,D2
LAB_0016:
     RTS
```

If I perform a diff on both files, the labels scramble/pollute the required result, which I'd like to be `SUB   #3,D1` added in file 2.

So I performed a pre-processing using a regex to change all labels by `LAB_XXXX`, like this:

```
def readlines(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = list(f)
        return [x.rstrip() for x in lines],[r.sub("LAB_XXXX",l).partition(";")[0] for l in lines]
```

and use `difflib` to print the diffs and it kind of works but it doesn't revert back to original label values of course. So I keep the original data, and parse difflib output to try to print the original data instead, but that's lame and doesn't work very well.

```
lines1,filtered_lines1 = readlines(file1)
lines2,filtered_lines2 = readlines(file2)

for line in difflib.unified_diff(filtered_lines1, filtered_lines2, fromfile=file1, tofile=file2, lineterm=''):
    m = re.match(r"@@..(\d+),(\d+).*(\d+),(\d+)",line)
    if m:
        start,end,start2,end2 = [int(x) for x in m.groups()]
        print(line)
        for i in range(start,start+end):
            print("{} <=> {}".format(lines1[i],lines2[i-start2+start]))
```

I've checked this answer [Fuzzy file diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471500/fuzzy-file-diff) but that doesn't cut it for me: pre-processing both files is already what I'm doing.

I'd like to instruct difflib (or any other diff mean) to ignore this `LAB_....` regex when comparing (a bit like you can compare data ignoring blanks, or case insensitive), so the original file content is printed (either side would do) when showing the diffs. For my above example I'd like:

```
LAB_0015:
     MOVE  #0,D0
@@added:235,1@@   <== this is just an example: 1 line added at line 235
>     SUB   #3,D1
     MOVE  #2,D2
LAB_0016:
     RTS
```

I'd prefer to keep it within python, but if I have to perform system calls for external commands that's okay too.

Comment: Do you need the diffing be done with python? The standard `diff` utility has an option `--ignore-matching-lines` that does what you want.

Comment: I didn't even see this option in `diff`. Very useful. I'd like to create a standalone tool which does other things, I'm using windows and `diff` comes with cygwin/MSYS, so not as a standard. I'd prefer python, but at this point non-python solutions are welcome.